# Extract all characters before numeric values in hive SQL

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I have a column `COD` with data that looks like this:

| COD |
| --- |
| TPP |
| PHONE_9985 |
| SMS@TELL-1256 |
| TEXT@123 |

I want to extract all characters before numeric values, expect result is:

| COD |
| --- |
| TPP |
| PHONE |
| SMS@TELL |
| TEXT |

I tried this, but without success:

```
substr(cod, 1, instr(cod, regexp_replace(cod, '[^0-9]','')))
```

Comment: What do you get when you use that?

Comment: I hope get the upper result so I test that

Comment: You need to give us the exact replacement logic.  It appears that you want to strip off trailing numbers, but sometimes other preceding characters also get trimmed.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen agreed, as in the desired results, even the underscore was removed

Answer (score 0):

use built in regexp replace

```sql
SELECT
    COD,
    CASE
        WHEN LOCATE('0', COD) = 0
            OR LOCATE('1', COD) = 0
            OR LOCATE('2', COD) = 0
            OR LOCATE('3', COD) = 0
            OR LOCATE('4', COD) = 0
            OR LOCATE('5', COD) = 0
            OR LOCATE('6', COD) = 0
            OR LOCATE('7', COD) = 0
            OR LOCATE('8', COD) = 0
            OR LOCATE('9', COD) = 0 THEN COD
        ELSE SUBSTR(COD, 1, LEAST(
            COALESCE(NULLIF(LOCATE('0', COD), 0), 9999999),
            COALESCE(NULLIF(LOCATE('1', COD), 0), 9999999),
            COALESCE(NULLIF(LOCATE('2', COD), 0), 9999999),
            COALESCE(NULLIF(LOCATE('3', COD), 0), 9999999),
            COALESCE(NULLIF(LOCATE('4', COD), 0), 9999999),
            COALESCE(NULLIF(LOCATE('5', COD), 0), 9999999),
            COALESCE(NULLIF(LOCATE('6', COD), 0), 9999999),
            COALESCE(NULLIF(LOCATE('7', COD), 0), 9999999),
            COALESCE(NULLIF(LOCATE('8', COD), 0), 9999999),
            COALESCE(NULLIF(LOCATE('9', COD), 0), 9999999)
        ) - 1)
    END AS characters_before_numeric
FROM
    your_table_name;
```

Comment: Not that this _won't_ generate the actual results the OP is expecting.  You should not be making answers without having full information.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen code has been updated

Comment: @Kiet if this solves your issue remember to up vote and mark as the answer. happy deving!

Comment: @Enigmativity it was undeleted before you even posted this.

Comment: @X3R0: please check your comand instr, it shows 0

Comment: @Kiet my code now supports when there isn't a number in the string

Comment: AS i know, instr is not support parameters as REGEXP, like: '[0-9]'

Comment: You are correct, I see Hive doesn't support that, here is the [official docs](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF)

Comment: @Kiet its a little bulky but we can use locate and then casing to do the same, this does get more complex if you want to add other values to break on.

Comment: See my updated code, please get back to me